# django project deploy success but Server Error (500)

Tags: python, django, heroku

i assemble all file that is nessasory like setting.py , project path ,profile etc.
i tried many times to solve this error but I did not get single success.
and also suggest me how to set template path dir in setting.py for my project path.

1.setting.py

```
import os
import django_heroku
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '...'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ravirajsavaliya.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #'content'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'contents.apps.ContentsConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = ''  # for production

STATIC_ROOT = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

2.Procfile without txt

```
web: gunicorn portfolio.wsgi
```

3. requirments.txt

```
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.6
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.8
Pillow==7.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.5
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.22.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.9
whitenoise==5.1.0
```

4.path
[path of files]
portfolio is app

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMDJ6.jpg

Comment: While you are developing the app, set DEBUG = True, not DEBUG = False like you have. This will show you more information about the error, which can not be solved without.
Also, setting.py has more SECURITY WARNINGs. Did you not read them?

Comment: When working with heroku, i create an txt file called runtime.txt with python-3.6.8 inside and add these lines in settings.py: SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

Comment: @danuker I tried but still error

Comment: You may want to set DEBUG=True to see the error detail. Why content app is commented in INSTALLED_APPS? I guess you got Apps aren't load yet error.

Comment: @riNg tried all but still error

Comment: ` heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=ravirajsavaliya.herokuapp.com request_id=56591992-db2
d-4b98-a7f4-617831c2fc5d fwd="49.34.113.170" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=163ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this error. I'm pretty sure it's a passenger_wsgi issue

Comment: Can you clarify how to fix this?